# Joint probability density function (PDF) of x^2 + y^2 < 1?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I am confused about what I should put in the following integration part of the PDF formula:

$$
P_{XY}(x,y) = \begin{cases} c & x^2+y^2 < 1 \\[8pt]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

To determine $c$, I use:

$$
1 = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \int^\infty_{-\infty} P_{XY}(x,y) dxdy
$$

$$
1 = \int_A^B \int_C^D c dxdy
$$

But what should I put in A, B, C and D for the case $x^2+y^2 < 1$?

---

if the condition is something like $0 \le y \le x \le 1$, I know that:

$$
1 = \int_0^1 \int_0^x c dxdy
$$

Comment: Hint: Polar coordinates.

Comment: After I briefly searched in Google, I still don't quite get it. I only know $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ implies $x + y < 1$

Comment: Because it doesn't. You have to change to the polar coordinate system to set up the integral.

Comment: Hint: $\int_{\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2} \ dx \ dy = \text{Area}(\Omega)$. That is, integrating the unit function over any region gives the area of the region. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the region, its a circle.

$y$ varies from $-1$ to $1$.

For a constant $y$, $x$ varies from $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$.

Thus, the integral would be:
$$1 = \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}} c \; dx \;dy$$

Comment: Then how do I find the constant $c$?

Comment: @Raptor by performing the integration